# Creating a tar.gz archive with Maven

Tags: maven-2, archive, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a Maven project, where under src/main directory there is a sub dir called output. this folder needs to be packaged into tar.gz. when using the assembly plugin as follows:

From the pom.xml:

```
<build>
<finalName>front</finalName>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
      </descriptors>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

the assembly.xml:

```
<assembly>
    <id>bundle</id> 
    <formats>
        <format>tar.gz</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/output</directory>
        </fileSet>
</fileSets>
</assembly>
```

My problem is that I am trying the outcome will be as running the tar utility itself, meaning when extracting to get **output** directory and all its content. what I get is the output folder wrapped with all the project path - name/src/main/output.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to configure the assembly descriptor to **not** include the base directory and to configure an output directory for the `fileSet`:

```
<assembly>
  <id>bundle</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>src/main/output</directory>
      <outputDirectory>output</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

With the above assembly descriptor, I get the following result (when running on a project reproducing the structure):

```
$ mvn clean assembly:assembly
...
$ cd target
$ tar zxvf Q3330855-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bundle.tar.gz 
output/
output/hello.txt
```

#### See also

- The Assembly [Descriptor Format](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) reference

Comment: just wanted to add, that if you need to choose individual files, includes/include can be used: http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/generate-assembly.html

Comment: vote++...Maybe it is also good to mention something about manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `outputDirectory` in the [`fileSet`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_fileSet).  That should remove the src/main/output directories.

```
<fileSet>
  <directory>src/main/output</directory>
  <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
</fileSet>
```

You may also need to set [`includeBaseDirectory`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_assembly) to false.  That would remove the name directory.

```
<assembly>
  <id>bundle</id> 
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <!-- ... -->
```