# Maven packaging of jars and other files

Tags: java, maven, ant, m2eclipse, packaging

I'm new to maven and have got a project with some dependencies. Now Maven should create a jar file of all **`/src/main/java`** files and put them into a directory **`A`**. I want to achieve these things in the build process :

- Put all dependency jars into a folder **`B`**
- Put some other files in the project into **`C`**.
- Then I need it **gzipped** and **zipped**
- Set some **execution permissions set in the gzip**,
- Finally **pushing** the two archives onto some network drive.

I've got that working with ANT but I want to do a clean port to Maven and not invoke the big ANT file.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Which plugins should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, have look at Maven Assembly Plugin. It might satisfy all your needs. I have used it but just little bit so I can just point you to information that you might need.

You create XML configuration file for this plugin called Assembly Descriptor that guides its operation.

There are some predefined available on the page of the plugin. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html At least the one with sources in zip will help you.

Assembly description is on http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html.

- You can copy dependencies in dependencySets.
- In fileSet, you can define file rights.
- For GZipping you can look at this topic [Creating a tar.gz archive with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330855/creating-a-tar-gz-archive-with-maven)
- If copying on shared drive cannot be handled by Assembly plugin, have look at maven-copy-plugin.

In case that Maven Assembly plugin  won't handle all the thing you need, you can use:
- Maven Copy Plugin - http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Maven-copy-plugin to copy source files
- Maven Dependency Plugin -http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/ for copy of all dependency JARs (goal copy-dependencies of the plugin)
- Maven Resources plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/ - if resources are what you need to copy.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I know all your requirements.

Maven can do things below by itself or with plugins:

0/ "mvn compile" will compile java files under your source folder, src/main/java is the default folder, and copy them into target/classes

1/ "mvn package" will zip a jar or war per your packaging

2/ maven resources plugin can do file operations

3/ maven assembly plugin can archive resources

4/ "mvn install" will install packaged jars into local maven repository

5/ "mvn deploy" will deploy packaged jars into remote maven repository if you have permission

Copy file into other project is not a wise idea when using Maven. It is more maven-style to add maven dependency in Project C pom.xml .

Comment: That is good point. Unlike Ant, Maven has some assumptions about project and predefined lifecycle. It handles a lot of operations out-of-the-box without much configuration.

E.g. for compilation, you do not need to tell it, where to look for source files. It uses its project structure, e.g. src/main/java for java source files and src/main/resources for application resources.

You can get the idea of what is Maven doing by reading article about it lifecycle. http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Maven Assembly Plugin (and a couple of other ways to do that), checkout [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

> Maven Shade Plugin
>
> This plugin provides the capability to package the artifact in an
>   uber-jar, including its dependencies and to shade - i.e. rename - the
>   packages of some of the dependencies.

Below is an example maven plugin configuration, for creating a jar output of a project which has jar dependencies:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupid>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupid>
                <artifactid>maven-shade-plugin</artifactid>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                          <mainclass>Main Class of the jar file</mainclass>
                        </transformer>
                      </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
           </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
```